# Function using setTimeout throws on subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, html, function, settimeout

I'm trying something easy, a typewriting effect:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = "eco eco"
var speed = 1;
function typeWriter(idtxt) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById(idtxt).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="remo-btn" onclick="typeWriter('demo')">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

When I hardcode the id, the code works as intended:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
```

But when I pass the id like this:

```js
document.getElementById(idtxt).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
```

It only returns the first letter, in this case, "e" (from `echo`).

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `innerHTML +=` is bad. It is slow and it is wasteful, and most of the time it is not necessary. Better change that line to `document.getElementById(idtxt).textContent = txt.slice(0, i+1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass in `idtxt` while calling `typeWriter` in the `setTimeout`:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = "eco eco"
var speed = 1000;
function typeWriter(idtxt) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById(idtxt).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(idtxt), speed);
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="remo-btn" onclick="typeWriter('demo')">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what this type of implementation is called `() => function ()` so that I can investigate it further. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), basically it wraps `typeWriter(idtxt)` in a function so you can pass in as an argument. It is similar to `function() { typeWriter(idtxt) }`.

Comment: If you don't know this part yet. I suggest you to use `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, idtxt)` as the answers shown below to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the `idtxt` variable is out of scope after the first call to `typeWriter`. You can pass the parameter to subsequent calls to `typeWriter` by passing it as the first argument of `setTimeout`. Like so:

```js
setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, idtxt);
```

You can read more about `setTimeout` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

And you can learn more about why this is necessary here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = "eco eco"
var speed = 1000;
function typeWriter(idtxt) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById(idtxt).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, idtxt);
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="remo-btn" onclick="typeWriter('demo')">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also, you probably meant for `speed` to equal `1000` (1 second). The delay of `setTimeout` is measured in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 offer other way for that.

for example with Promise management:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  ,    txt  = 'Hello, world!'
  ;
async function typeWriter(idtxt)
  {
  const elm = document.getElementById(idtxt)
  for await (let letter of txt)
    {
    elm.textContent += letter
    await delay(500)
    }
  }
```

```html
<button class="remo-btn" onclick="typeWriter('demo')">remo-btn</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I try to follow the code, but I have a hard time understanding some parts. I need to improve my knowledge in JavaScript. But thank you very much, this could help me in making my code more functional

Comment: You don't need to convert the string to an array, strings are iterable. You're using exactly that to spread the string into an array. And you don't need `for await` here, since your iterator is synchronous. Doesn't matter that the content of the loop is async. So `for (let letter of txt)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

change  `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed );` to  `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, idtxt );`
you are missing to send `idtxt` argument

PS cahnge also `var speed = 1000;`  1s == 1000ms

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = "eco eco"
var speed = 1000;
function typeWriter(idtxt) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById(idtxt).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, idtxt );
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="remo-btn" onclick="typeWriter('demo')">
<p id="demo"></p>
```